# Count how many times value appears in table

Tags: django

Within my app, I have some forms that allow the user to select from a dropdown and I'm trying to count how many times `RED`, `GREEN` and `AMBER` have been selected across 20 different fields.

I was looking at

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(count = Count('my_charfield'))
```

But I'm not sure how to count the values rather than the field type?

Thanks

Comment: can you add your models to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. Something to this effect:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate(
     red=Sum(
         Case(When(my_charfield="RED", then=1),
              output_field=IntegerField())
     ),
     green=Sum(
         Case(When(my_charfield="GREEN", then=1),
              output_field=IntegerField())
     ),
     amber=Sum(
         Case(When(account_type="AMBER", then=1),
              output_field=IntegerField())
     )
)
```

which will then return a dictionary of values

```
{red: 1, green: 10, amber: 101}
```